# Запретить окнам получать фокус

Tags: windows, окно

Добрый день.
Подскажите, можно ли как-нибудь в windows10 сделать, чтобы активным окно мог делать только пользователь?
Суть проблемы в том, что когда идёт сборка проекта, по ходу сборки открываются консольные окна, которые становятся активными поверх текущего окна. Можно ли что-то с этим сделать?

Comment: а что за окна ? cmd ->  start /min C:\test.bat

Comment: @PauloBerezini в основном такие: `call "%USERPROFILE%\some_script.bat"`

Comment: Так как я сказал пробовали ?

Comment: @PauloBerezini я не могу это менять

Comment: можете написать тогда свой батник, который будет запускать другие батники с /min?

Comment: @azEsm проект ваш или не ваш? Как это вы не можете что-то менять?

Comment: @PavelMayorov строго говоря, не мой. Принадлежит работодателю и то, что касается скриптов запуска не в моей власти

Comment: В основном эти окна запускаются градлом тасками типа JavaExec